# Accessing Zonal Statistics for QGIS on Mac?

Tags: qgis, mac, zonal-statistics

I've just updated to QGIS 3.4 for my MacOS (10.12). I'm trying to run some occupancy analyses and am looking to extract attribute data for a polygon grid from an underlaying raster file. ZonalStats sounds to be the ideal plugin for this, and is apparently built into this version of Q but I cannot find it anywhere and / or via any search within Q. Please any suggestions how I can access?

Comment: This isn't a Mac-specific issue, it's a difference between the QGIS 2.x and 3.x series. Many QGIS tools that used to be accessible as plugins or through menus have been moved to the Processing Toolbox.

Answer (score 2):

The [Zonal Statistics tool](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#zonal-statistics) is in the [Processing toolbox](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing/toolbox.html), in the Raster Analysis provider.

[image]